# How to Access Fields in Nested Classes after Deserialzing JSON to C# .Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have successfully used JSON.NET to deserialize the [AWS pricing data](https://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/deprecated/ec2/pricing-on-demand-instances.json).

Here are the classes that were generated from the JSON using json2csharp.net:

```
public class Prices
{
    public string USD { get; set; }
}

public class ValueColumn
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Prices prices { get; set; }
}

public class Size
{
    public string size { get; set; }
    public List<ValueColumn> valueColumns { get; set; }
}

public class InstanceType
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Size> sizes { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public string region { get; set; }
    public List<InstanceType> instanceTypes { get; set; }
}

public class Config
{
    public string rate { get; set; }
    public List<string> valueColumns { get; set; }
    public List<string> currencies { get; set; }
    public List<Region> regions { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public double vers { get; set; }
    public Config config { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure how to be able to access the data fields in the Prices class when starting with a RootObject (which represents the root of the deserialized JSON object).  Assuming my RootObject is named 'root', I can get as far as:

```
Console.WriteLine(root.config.regions.count);
```

But I don't know how to recursively access the actual items in the regions list, then the instanceTypes list, etc. until I get all the way to the Prices class.

Said slightly differently, I need help recursing my deserialized JSON object from the root-level, all the way down to the leaf-level, so I can access the data fields there (and anywhere in between).  I hope I've been clear as this is my first time working with JSON/deserializations/C#.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you probably want to do:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(awsJsonData);
foreach(var region in rootObject.config)
{
    //Work with regions here
    foreach(var instanceType in region.instanceTypes)
    {
        //work with this regions instance types here
        foreach(var size in instanceType.sizes)
        {
            //work with this instance types sizes here
            (etc...)
        }
    }
}
```

Once you get all the way down to the foreach price in valuecolumn.prices, you can compose the data however you wish as the parent object is available in the foreach scope.

Comment: Hi Bob!  Great stab at this, and thank you.  That's currently what I have actually, but something feels wrong about nesting so many levels deep.  It seems to work, you're right, but it just feels like there is probably a more "correct" way of doing this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ

```
    RootObject root = new RootObject();
    var regions = root.config.regions;
    var instanceTypes = regions.Select(x => x.instanceTypes);
    var sizes = instanceTypes.Select(s => s.Select(c => c.sizes));
    var valueColumns = sizes.Select(v => v.Select(p => p.Select(q => q.valueColumns)));
    var prices = valueColumns.Select(x => x.Select(p => p.Select(r => r.Select(q => q.prices.USD))));
```